# AutoIt WinSetState, how to maximize quickbooks?

Tags: autoit

```
WinSetState("[Class:quickbooks pro 2015]", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
WinSetState("quickbooks pro 2015", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

I'm using both lines since I don't know which would work.  I can't get it to maximize quickbooks.

I've tried all sorts of names I found in the properties of the application, all it did was maximize the property windows of quickbooks...

I thought maybe quickbook for some reason won't let you, but I used the [Active] and it maximized it just fine.

How should I do this?

Comment: Your first try won't work, because the **classname** of Quickbooks isn't the same as the **window title**. The second won't work, either, because matching the window title is case-sensitive, and I highly doubt that Quickbooks is shown as *quickbooks* in the title.

Comment: Okay.  I made changes and added capital letters.  It still doesn't work.  I can get this to work for excel, word, and some other ones, but not quickbook for some reason

Comment: So use WinSpy or something else and find out what the actual classname for the window is, instead of just thrashing about wildly trying to get lucky. Trying to find it by title must be an **exact match**, including capitalization, punctuation, number of spaces, special characters, and anything else it contains.

Comment: Not sure why you think i'm thrashing around...I been trying this for past few hours.  I tried using WinGetName, copied and pasted, that didn't work.

Tried finding a WinGetClass function, but I couldn't get it to work, so I came here.

I'll try WinSpy, didn't think about other programs that could find it

Comment: :-) Thrashing around was meant to convey *trying things guessing at what it might be* instead of finding a tool that would provide you the proper classname. Glad I could help. But you can't edit your question to put the solution in there. If you'd like to share what you learned or found, do so by writing an answer in the space below meant for that purpose. If you don't think your solution will be helpful to others, it doesn't need to be here. In either case, it's inappropriate to edit your question to include the answer. (I've rolled back your edit for that reason.)

Comment: ah, I see.  I understand, new user here.  I'm use to reddit style.

Comment: Yeah, we're not them, or anything like any other site. This site is pretty strict about it's guidelines to make sure we're not like anyone else out there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`WinSetState("name")` didn't work.

I was able to use `WinSetState([Class:"name"])` instead.

I found the class name using WinLister.